# preg_grep pattern for checking url prefix

Tags: php, validation

I am trying to write a validator for a URL prefix that will check if it starts with http or https, ends with a forward slash, and is case insensitive.

Here is what I am going for but I'm not sure if I am structuring the pattern properly:

```
$value = "http://fakeprefix/";
$pattern = "/^(http|https)://, /$, i";
$validator = preg_grep($pattern, $value);
```

I look forward to hearing back from you and appreciate your assistance.

Comment: What happened when you ran this code?

Comment: I'm not sure if I am writing the pattern properly for preg_grep to understand.  Looking for some confirmation if I am on the right track first

Comment: Correct. regex: "^(http|https):\/\/"

You can try here.:
https://regex101.com/

Comment: /^(http|https):\/\//i successfully checks the beginning of the string for http:// and https://, the final question is how to additionally check to make sure the strings ends with a forward slash as well

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `filter_var('http://example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);` ?
([doc](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.filter-var.php))

Edit, after your comment and @cOle2's

You can also have a look at [parse_url](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.parse-url.php). Here is an example  :

```
var_dump(parse_url("http://fakeprefix/"));
```

Outputs :

```
array(3) {
  ["scheme"]=>
  string(4) "http"
  ["host"]=>
  string(10) "fakeprefix"
  ["path"]=>
  string(1) "/"
}
```

Then you can check and validate the different parts.

Comment: My apologies, the prefix doesn't end with ".com" so a standard URL check won't work

Comment: A valid URL via `filter_var` doesn't require the protocol to be `http` or `https` like the OP requires, ie could be `ftp`, `ssh` etc.